# Permission with google playconsole

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

So i been developing my own 2D shooter an endless runner. I know felt that its in the testing stage. But in google play console it says that the app ask for  following 9 permissions.

Ive been searching far and wild for how to fix in the manifest. And i found other people solve it by copy the manifest.xml file to Assets/plugins/Android. And change the permission and that it should work. I tried it maybe 20 times now and it still not working. So now i opened the APK file in Android studio and found this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.xiaomi.sdk.permission.PAYMENT" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.xiaomi.permission.AUTH_SERVICE" />
```

but the manifest in the the Asset/plugins/Android folder only includes this:

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? I really dont know what to do i cant edit the manifest directly in Android studio.

This is what shows as error in google playstore
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE, android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, android.permission.GET_TASKS, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, com.xiaomi.permission.AUTH_SERVICE, com.xiaomi.sdk.permission.PAYMENT

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use any plugins in your project, most of them may have their own manifest file. Build system combines those manifests into one. Check your Plugins/Android folder (it's possible to use built-in search with a request like "AndroidManifest.xml" or something), find out manifest files and then you can edit them. Note: changing "local" manifests may cause some problems with plugins.

Comment: Ya, it reminds me, during the development i added some plugins that im the end not even used in the finieshed product. Maybe t will work if i delete those plugin files.